# slideToggle overriding media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a slideToggle navigation only on mobile. However, the settings are also affecting the larger browser sizes. On the large browser, the first child is hidden:

```
#menu-menu-1 li {
    display: block;
}

#menu-menu-1 li:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

And on mobile, it is reversed. The first child is shown, the rest hidden:

```
#menu-menu-1 li {
    display: none;
}

#menu-menu-1 li:first-child {

    display: block;
}
```

And thus, because the first child is now set to `display:block`, you can use this slideToggle:

```
  $('#menu-menu-1 li:first-child').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#menu-menu-1 li:first-child').siblings().slideToggle();

    });
```

This works fine, until you use it to slide the content back up, and change the browser size back. That makes **all** the siblings set back to `display:none`, even though the larger browser media queries has them at `display:block` .

Is there a way as soon as the browser is expanded, the slideToggle settings are ignored?

Comment: Yes, you can ignore them at larger browser settings by using a if statement to chekc before executing your function.

Comment: I still think it would require a reload to override the settings? Because the function is affecting everything, regardless of what size you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a module I wrote to help with the problem of triggering javascript when I want it on resize and to help with chekcing the size:

```
jQuery(function($){

    //resize window events

    //store the reference outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);

    function checkWidth() {
        var windowSize = $window.width();

        return windowSize;
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();

    // Bind event listener
    //remove console.log from production version
    $(window).resize(function(){
        console.log('checkWidth: ', checkWidth() + 'px' );
        if(checkWidth() >= [yourDesiredWidth]){
            //do something
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Ooh this looks interesting. What does it do?

Comment: it tells you in the console how large the window is and allows you to react at specific sizes.